# Puzzling post and pre-increment behavior of reverse_iterators and base

Tags: c++, iterator

Consider the toy program (post.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main() {
        vector<int > a;
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
                a.push_back(i);
        auto it=a.rbegin();
        while(it!=a.rend()) {
                if ((*it % 2)==0) {
                                cout << "about to erase "<<*it<<endl;
                                a.erase((it++).base());
                }
                else {
                        ++it;
                }
        }
        for(auto it2=a.begin(); it2 != a.end(); it2++) {
                cout << *it2 << endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

What I am trying to do is to test for evenness, and then delete the current number, since `(it++)` should return the current iterator and then advance the iterator. This is what I get as the output:

```
$ ./post 
about to erase 8
about to erase 6
about to erase 4
about to erase 2
about to erase 0
0
2
4
6
8
```

If, however, I change the line `a.erase((it++).base());` to `a.erase((++it).base());`, I get the correct behavior. Why is this?

Useful clarification: I am using `base()` since reverse_iterators cannot be used in `erase()`. There is an application where I want to go reverse on the vector to erase stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `base()` of a reverse iterator is offset by 1. So `rbegin().base() == end()` and `rend().base() == begin()`.

This is nothing other than the generalization of this reverse loop:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i)
{
    mutate(array[N - i - 1]);
}   //                 ^^^
```

The loop traverses the array in reverse order, and note how we need a `- 1` on the "iterator".

---

**Update:** Now let's investigate what a reverse iterator is: It is simply a wrapper around a bidirectional iterator. Suppose the reverse iterator is called `it`; then it has an ordinary iterator member `it.base()`. For example, `v.rbegin().base() == v.end()`. When you say `++it`, that just calls `--it.base()` (conceptually). The real magic is the dereference operation: This has to give us *one element before* the underlying iterator:

```
*it == *(it.base() - 1)
```

This is exactly the same arithmetic which told us that the *i* <sup>th</sup> element *from the back* of an array is offset by one:`array[N - i - 1]`. This also shows us why we need a *bidirectional* iterator to form reverse iterators.

Now it is clear how we can erase via reverse iterators from a container that does not invalidate iterators, such as any node-based container:

```
if (meets_condition(*it))   // this examines *(it.base() - 1)!
{
     auto b = it.base();
     container.erase(it.base() - 1);
     it = std::reverse_iterator(b);
}
```

Remember that this requires that erasing does not invalidate any iterators other than the erasee, like in any node-based container. Erasing like this from a vector would be even more difficult. For a vector, erasing invalidates *all* iterators past the erasee (in forward direction), so we have to use the return value of the `erase` function:

```
if (meets_condition(*ut))   // again, examine *(it.base() - 1)
{
    it = std::reverse_iterator(container.erase(it.base() - 1));
}
```

In a picture (we're removing element "5"):

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |     =:   v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
              ^   ^
              |   |
|             |   +--- it.base()
|             |
|             +--- *it == *(it.base() - 1)
|
V

+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
          ^   ^
          |   |
          |   +--- result of v.erase(it.base() - 1)
          |
          +--- *(std::reverse_iterator(v.erase(it.base() - 1)))
```

Comment: Thanks! But how would I go about doing what I am trying to do, namely delete elements while iterating in reverse on an STL container? In fact let me update my question at the top to include this.

Comment: @highBandWidth: I thought you already knew how to get the correct behaviour?!

Comment: Ahh, I see. I guess you have answered the question, but then the program seems to depend on this little quirk. Is there a way to get the iterator corresponding to the same element? So that '(*it)== *(it.real_base())'?

Comment: @highBandWidth: There's no quirk. Look at the array loop again: This is exactly what a reverse iterator is: just a wrapper around a bidirectional iterator. You simply offset the base by one. That's precisely what the dereference operation does. But to be honest, I'm not actually sure whether this is well-defined behaviour, because it looks like you're invalidating the iterator. I have to think about that.

Comment: The *correct way* is a bit trickier to get to, and it is not what is written in the question (which is undefined behavior), so my assumption is that he does not know it. The correct way of doing this would be to reconstruct a `reverse_iterator` out of the value returned by `erase`.

Comment: @highBandWidth: That question is about `std::set`, not `std::vector`. The guarantees of the operations on the different containers are not the same. In particular in a `std::set`, the `erase` operation invalidates *only* the erased iterator, while on a `std::vector` it invalidates *all* iterators from the erased one to the end of the container.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, where can I find the guarantees on the operations? I couldn't find them on the `set` page, for example at http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set.html

Comment: @highBandWidth: Uhm... the last paragraph in the **Description** in your link actually says.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: You're right. The `base()` iterator is just the actual iterator itself, which *will* be invalidated by the `erase` operation. Let me write something up.

Comment: I don't think the last piece of code is correct. I would expect something alike: `it = std::reverse_iterator(vector.erase(it.base()-1))`. That is, obtain the iterator to delete from the reverse iterator, take the result of the call to `erase` which is the a valid iterator to the element after the removed one and populate `it` with that value. Unlike forward iteration, in this case we still want to do the `++it` at the end of the iteration since the value returned by `erase` is an iterator *before* the one we are processing when seen in the backwards direction.

Comment: ... now whether this is a good option or not... I would still prefer using the *erase-remove* idiom, which can be combined with a backwards pass (if as the user suggests) there is an extra condition that means the iteration should stop.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Are you sure? in my code, `b` is never invalidated, only `b - 1` is...

Comment: The code in the question uses a `std::vector` for which `erase` invalidates all iterators after the one being removed.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Oh, of course - I was thinking `set`. OK, I'll make a note of that.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your question, but a solution to your problem: Use the *erase-remove* idiom that is more efficient than what you are currently doing:

```
bool even( int value ) { return !(value%2); }
std::vector<int> v = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 }; // Assuming C++11 or build it otherwise
v.erase( std::remove_if( v.begin(), v.end(), even ),
         v.end() );
```

The difference in efficiency is that `remove_if` will copy only the values left in the container *once* to the final location, while your algorithm might copy some of the elements multiple times. In particular 9 will be copied 4 times, 7 3 times and so on.

Comment: Thanks! But you see the reason I was doing it this way is that in my real application I need to go reverse since I know after a while I can break out of the loop. Can you go in reverse and conditionally break out of the loop with erase-remove?

Comment: @highBandWidth: You cannot. What the best solution depends on your actual requirements, and those are missing from the question.

Comment: May be I should ask a separate question. I need to go over a vector or list, go over the container in reverse, conditionally remove elements, and also conditionally break out of the loop after a while.

Comment: @highBandWidth: The question is how *conditionally* is determined. One thing you can do is walk backwards without modifying until you reach the condition, at which point you can use the *erase-remove* idiom. While this requires two passes over the end of the container, you will avoid the multiple copies and that might actually provide a gain.